# Построение сложной столбчатой диаграммы pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Есть датафрейм работников НИИ. У них есть параметры name, rating(0 - 700) и academic_degree(1-3). Нужно построить столбчатую диаграмму, по оси у rating, по х name, причём цвет столбца определяется параметром academic_degree.

Данные выглядят примерно так: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1QlJslTtCtCMLEb0fwdx_4bfTJk17sj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Пример данных должен быть прямо в вопросе. Только не в виде скриншота.

Comment: А вообще все нужные параметры есть там, включая `color`, просто указываете параметры и всё https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: Хотя я не совсем возможно прав про цвет, в общем приведите данные. Там ещё вопрос в том, может ли быть несколько разных status у одной позиции name/rating или нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил csv. Основная проблема с настройкой цвета.

Comment: так гистограмму или столбчатую диаграмму?

Comment: @strawdog, исправил. Нужна гистограмма

Comment: ну вас не поймешь. сами написали, что нужна гистограмма, а приняли ответ со столбчатой диаграммой. Вы вопрос тогда откорректируйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я был не прав, нужно использовать параметр `palette`. Ну и, чтобы всё уместилось, лучше имена писать по оси `y`. Цвета сами подберёте наиболее подходящие, я не дизайнер что-то совсем. Ну и по-хорошему легенду цветов хорошо бы написать где-то рядом.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

colors= {
    'Нет': 'blue',
    'к.м.н.': 'cyan',
    'д.м.н.': 'magenta'
}

df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv', index_col=0)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,15))
sns.barplot(x='rating', y='name', palette=df.academic_degree.map(colors).values, data=df);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и, возможно, чтобы лучше видно было различие в рейтинге, нужно указать ограничения на ось `x`:

```py
plt.xlim(df.rating.min() - 1,df.rating.max() + 1);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Я не совсем уверен, что правильно понял, что вы хотите, но если речь о гистограмме, то можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv", index_col=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

colors = {"Нет":"gray", "к.м.н.":"blue", "д.м.н.":"red"}
data = []
labels = []
for i in df["academic_degree"].unique():
    data.append(df.loc[df["academic_degree"]==i, "rating"].values)
    labels.append(i)

ax.hist(data, 10, alpha=0.75, label=labels)
ax.legend(prop={'size': 10})
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там в данных имена не повторяются. И ещё сами имена длинные и их много

Comment: @CrazyElf  а причем здесь имена? вопрос был про гистограмму рейтингов и ученых степеней.

Comment: "по х name", но да, видимо вопрос про другое, возможно я не так понял